# CSS file not registering through add_action

Tags: css, wp-enqueue-style

Im having a problem to register and load a gallery css code from my home page. Rest of the styles are loading fine, but this flexslider is not registering. Any guidance appreciated.

```
<?php 

function theme_styles() {

wp_enqueue_style ('normalize', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/normalize.css');
wp_enqueue_style ('grid', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/grid.css');
wp_enqueue_style ('main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');

wp_register_style( 'flexslider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/flexslider.css' );
if( is_page( 'home' ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'flexslider' );
}
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_styles' );

// Enable custom menus
add_theme_support( 'menus' );

?>
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the conditional / what have you tried to solve this problem?

Comment: Yes, I removed the conditional, did not work.

Comment: Maybe you really want to test for `is_front_page()`, not `is_page('home')`; [is_front_page()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page) tests for your static front page.

Comment: If you remove the conditional, is anything at all output? Or is the link output, but the stylesheet isn't loaded (e.g. 404)? Can we see a **live link** to the site demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, I will check those after office. Many thknks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary issue is an incorrect template conditional tag:

```
if( is_page( 'home' ) ) {}
```

This returns true if the current context is a *static page*, with the slug `home`. I presume that you're *actually* wanting to test for the **Site Front Page** - in which case you need to use the [`is_front_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page) conditional:

```
if ( is_front_page() ) {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'flexslider' );
}
```

If the stylesheet still isn't being output, we'll need further debugging information.

Comment: You may also consider checking for `is_home()`, which looks for the blog index page.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, I will check those after office. Many thknks

Comment: Dear Chip Bennett, your solution worked like a charm, Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing all points of failure and do what you know will work without any question. Then move forward from there one step at a time.

This is what I would do first just to make sure I am not completely insane!

```
<link type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/flexslider.css">
```

Then if that is outputting then move forward. If not, fairly simple fix at that point. Coding really is full-time trouble shooting. :)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, I will check those after office. Many thknks

Comment: Why would you suggest the OP hard-code the stylesheet into the template instead of enqueueing it properly the OP is already doing?

Comment: Because this is a safe and "goof-proof" way to make sure that the file is indeed located in the correct dir. Its sort like calling the computer repair guy because your box wont boot.... and he asks if you have it plugged in. :)